# TicTacToe-Game in java, variable boardsize, checkWin() function is giving me trouble

Tags: java

I am having trouble writing the `checkWin()` function for my tictactoe game. Can someone explain to me how I can check for a win in a variable board? The win condition is if you complete a row or a column.

Comment: please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand what you've tried and what code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting it up into a bunch of smaller methods:

```
    checkWinVertical()
    checkWinHorizontal()
    checkWinDiagonal()
```

which should be easier to handle. I can't really help much more without a code fragment that you've tried- does this help?